# Wamp server can't connect to localhost

Tags: wampserver

I am having a problem with wamp server (again). First the icon would not turned green so I change the port to 8080 and now it turns green. However, when I visit localhost, I just get the message in the screenshot below.

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here? Same when I try to go to PhpMyAdmin. I have version 2.1

Answer (score 12):

try http://localhost:8080
(or http://127.0.0.1:8080 if there is a problem with the resolution of localhost)

you changed the port and I am not sure if you reflect this in your request.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Skype on in the background? If so turn it of restart your web server on port 80.

**Edit:** Like said in another response check for anything on port 80 and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Check your system for any program that uses the port 80, and turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work:
Check in which Drive your Windows OS is installed. If it is E, F or other then C, then install wampp in that particular drive.

If `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package` is not intalled then install from  : [Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=8328)

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue during the installation.
This error is due to

1) if some other service is running on the same port

2) if some other application may block your application.

For checking

1.) Select the server icon. Select "www directory" and make sure it is pointing to where it should and that there are files there. --- It points to my Documents/wamp/www --- where there are an index and your test files.

2.) Select the server icon. Select Apache. Select service. Select "test port 80". See what port 80 is actually used by. --- I get "your port 80 is actually used by:......

Here you can find your port is used by which service. 
If you have iis running remove that temporarily now by `control panel-> uninstall program -. turn window feature on/off -> iis`.

After this restart your system and run wampserver now. It will work  Hope this may help

Answer (score 0):

Check in your hosts file to see if there is a entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

if there is a # before it like this

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

delete the hash as that is a comment

you will find your host file at:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc